# html code for fading pictures one after another

Tags: html

I am a novice site builder.  I have photos that I would like to put on my website and I would like to have them on a continuous transition one after the other.  Could someone provide me with an HTML code where all I have to do in include the name of the pictures that I already have on file.  They are different sizes, but when they transition in, I would like t have them the same size as well.  They are in jpg format.

Thanks to anyone that can help with this?

Answer (score 3):

You want to use jQuery for this so it will be much easier... I suppose you have HTML looking somthing like this (simplified):

```
<div class="images">
    <img src="..." />
    <img src="..." />
    <img src="..." />
    ...
</div>
```

There are many image sliders out there with all kinds of functionality but if fading is all you need then writing a few lines of code may be easier.

Do something like this (using jQuery):

```
$(function() {
    var images = $(".images img").hide();
    var current = 0;
    setInterval(function() {
        var next = ((current + 1) % images.length);
        images.eq(current).fadeOut();
        images.eq(next).fadeIn();
        current = next;
    });
});
```

Don't forget to set CSS style to:

```
.images
{
    position: relative;
}
.images img
{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}
```

This is a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/chQcz/) that rotates images every 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for isn't HTML code, but Javascript (or CSS) code. I suggest you look up tutorials on how image sliders and galleries work and are structured. It is especially simple with the jQuery Javascript library.

I have looked up a couple of links of simple sliders and galleries you can try to understand and implement:

http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/automatic-image-slider-w-css-jquery/

http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2010/10/20-stunning-jquery-image-sliders-and-tutorials-for-creating-your-own.html